# how to place the Google Maps V3 at the center of web page?

Tags: html, css, google-maps-api-3, web

I want to ask you something. I make the application web with the Google Maps inside. But the problem is my map is in the left side of my web page. How to place the maps at the center of web page?

This is my screenshot :

[image]

So, how to place the maps at the center of green part? Now, the maps is at the left side of the green part. Please help. Thank You.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add a stylesheet that has margin "auto" on left and right side.

```
<style type="text/css">
div#googleMap { margin: 0 auto 0 auto; }
</style>

<div id="googleMap"><!-- contains map --></div>
```